# .NET equivalent of the old vb left(string, length) function

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

As a non-.NET programmer I'm looking for the .NET equivalent of the old Visual Basic function `left(string, length)`. It was lazy in that it worked for any length string. As expected, `left("foobar", 3) = "foo"` while, most helpfully, `left("f", 3) = "f"`.

In .NET `string.Substring(index, length)` throws exceptions for everything out of range. In Java I always had the Apache-Commons lang.StringUtils handy. In Google I don't get very far searching for string functions.

---

**@Noldorin** - Wow, thank you for your VB.NET extensions! My first encounter, although it took me several seconds to do the same in C#:

```
public static class Utils
{
    public static string Left(this string str, int length)
    {
        return str.Substring(0, Math.Min(length, str.Length));
    }
}
```

Note the static class and method as well as the `this` keyword. Yes, they are as simple to invoke as `"foobar".Left(3)`. See also [C# extensions on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx).

Comment: As a footnote, return new string( str.Take( length ).ToArray() ); also works. I imagine using substring is probably faster.

Comment: One can also use `return str.Length > length ? str.Remove(length) : str;`

Comment: Another way: `return string.Concat(str.Take(length));`

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Here's an extension method that will do the job.

```vb
<System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()> _
Public Function Left(ByVal str As String, ByVal length As Integer) As String
    Return str.Substring(0, Math.Min(str.Length, length))
End Function
```

This means you can use it just like the old VB `Left` function (i.e. `Left("foobar", 3)` ) or using the newer VB.NET syntax, i.e.

```vb
Dim foo = "f".Left(3) ' foo = "f"
Dim bar = "bar123".Left(3) ' bar = "bar"
```

Comment: Was just typing up an example of an extension method.

Comment: @Oded: They most certainly do in VB.NET 9. You need to specify the Extension attribute, which is quite different to the method for C#. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384936.aspx

Comment: The original question stated nothing about an extension method. Seems to be going off on a tangent.

Comment: @Andrew Robinson: Not really, I think. Just because he didn't mention it, it doesn't mean it's not a valid (addition to the) answer. In fact, because he didn't refer to it, I suspected it was likely to be of *more* interest to him. Adding extra info that could be helpful never hurts. :)

Answer (score 40):

Another one line option would be something like the following:

```
myString.Substring(0, Math.Min(length, myString.Length))
```

Where myString is the string you are trying to work with.

Comment: This was the first solution that came to my mind. I thought there must be an easier/build-in way. But there is none...

Answer (score 36):

Add a reference to the Microsoft.VisualBasic library and you can use the [Strings.Left](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.strings.left.aspx) which is *exactly* the same method.

Comment: Much simpler solution - what's the point of reinventing the wheel?

Comment: What if I want completely get rid of VB references in  my .Net application ?

Comment: This is like using a fork to stir your soup when you can't find the spoon.

Comment: @JennyO'Reilly while your metaphor is colorful it's misapplied.  The OP asked for the VB function and this is exactly what he asked for.

Comment: It's just adding another library of functions to save you time.  You can cover your eyes when you see the "VB" if it makes you feel better.

Comment: Adding 4 or more lines of code to do what one line can is like gargling peanut butter to quench your thirst.

Answer (score 18):

Don't forget the null case:

```
public static string Left(this string str, int count)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(str) || count < 1)
        return string.Empty;
    else
        return str.Substring(0,Math.Min(count, str.Length));
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Use:

```
using System;

public static class DataTypeExtensions
{
    #region Methods

    public static string Left(this string str, int length)
    {
        str = (str ?? string.Empty);
        return str.Substring(0, Math.Min(length, str.Length));
    }

    public static string Right(this string str, int length)
    {
        str = (str ?? string.Empty);
        return (str.Length >= length)
            ? str.Substring(str.Length - length, length)
            : str;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

It shouldn't error, returns nulls as empty string, and returns trimmed or base values. Use it like "testx".Left(4) or str.Right(12);

Answer (score 6):

You could make your own:

```
private string left(string inString, int inInt)
{
    if (inInt > inString.Length)
        inInt = inString.Length;
    return inString.Substring(0, inInt);
}
```

Mine is in C#, and you will have to change it for Visual Basic.

Answer (score 3):

You can either wrap the call to substring in a new function that tests the length of it as suggested in other answers (the right way)  or use the Microsoft.VisualBasic namespace and use left directly (generally considered the wrong way!)

Comment: You should not use Try...Catch to catch something that you can very easily check for beforehand.

Comment: Why is using the VisualBasic namespace considered the "wrong way"?  That's precisely why it is included.  It's part of VB.

Answer (score 3):

Another technique is to extend the string object by adding a Left() method.

Here is the source article on this technique:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384936.aspx

Here is my implementation (in VB):

```
Module StringExtensions

    <Extension()>
    Public Function Left(ByVal aString As String, Length As Integer)
        Return aString.Substring(0, Math.Min(aString.Length, Length))
    End Function

End Module
```

Then put this at the top of any file in which you want to use the extension:

```
Imports MyProjectName.StringExtensions
```

Use it like this:

```
MyVar = MyString.Left(30)
```

Answer (score 3):

I like doing something like this:

```
string s = "hello how are you";
s = s.PadRight(30).Substring(0,30).Trim(); //"hello how are you"
s = s.PadRight(3).Substring(0,3).Trim(); //"hel"
```

Though, if you want trailing or beginning spaces then you are out of luck.

I really like the use of Math.Min, it seems to be a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

Just in a very special case:

If you are doing this left and you will check the data with some partial string, for example:

`if(Strings.Left(str, 1)=="*") ...;`

Then you can also use C# instance methods, such as `StartsWith` and `EndsWith` to perform these tasks.

`if(str.StartsWith("*"))...;`

Answer (score 1):

In newer versions of C#, you can use range notation with strings.

[Explore ranges of data using indices and ranges - C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/ranges-indexes)

```
string Domain = @"www.microsoft.com";
// left(), start at 0 and return 4 chars
string First4Chars = Domain[..4]; // "www."
// right(), 4 chars from the end, going to end
string Last4Chars = Domain[^4..]; // ".com"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid using an extension method and prevent an under-length error, try this

```
string partial_string = text.Substring(0, Math.Min(15, text.Length)) 
// example of 15 character max
```