# Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.WorksheetFunction does not contain all the functions in excel

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop

I am trying to call excel functions from C#. I can use the following code to get the excel functions:

```
Application app = new Application();
WorksheetFunction functions = app.WorksheetFunction;
var sum = functions.Sum(1, 2);
```

I can get the function like SUM from the WorksheetFunction object. But now all the functions are there, like LEFT, RIGHT, DATE etc. Can I find them somewhere else?

Comment: You mean on the site?

Comment: were you able to use sum?

Comment: I've always assumed it's because those functions exist in VBA, or in your case, C#. Can you just use the C# LEFT, RIGHT or DATE, etc., functions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.Net equivalent of the old vb left(string, length) function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/844059/net-equivalent-of-the-old-vb-leftstring-length-function)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like below for example

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

static void Main(string[] args)
{

     Application a = new Application();
     double x = a.WorksheetFunction.Sum(1, 2);
     Console.WriteLine("Sum = {0}", x);

}
```

**EDIT**

```
using IExcel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
```

Then declare and initialise a IWorkSheetFunction object

```
IExcel.IWorksheetFunction iwf = new IExcel.IWorksheetFunction();
```

Now you can use the functions as in

```
double result = iwf.NormDist(1,2,3,4);
```

Comment: Sum is in the WorksheetFunction. LEFT, RIGTH, Date are not.

Comment: This interface does not have LEFT, RIGHT and DATE functions