# In C#, what is the equivalent to the Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings module

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

In C#, what is the equivalent to the Strings module, which defines string helper methods in the `Microsoft.VisualBasic` namespace.  It provides some useful procedures which can be used to perform string operations, such as `Left`.

Comment: What kind of string operations? What do you need more that isn't included in the `string` extension methods?

Comment: You can use `Microsoft.VisualBasic` in C# as well, just add a reference to the assembly. However most of the functionality is already covered by the `String` class.

Comment: Left for example:
`System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Left(sEncryptionKey, 8))`

Comment: `Left()` is replaced by `Substring()`: `sEncryptionKey.Substring(startIndex: 0, length: 8)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the static and nonstatic methods of class `String` that perform splits, replaces etc.

[MSDN String Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/System.String%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

---

As a direct example for your problem, you could create an extension method. The code looks a bit like this:

```
public static class Utils {
    public static string Left(this string str, int length)
    {
        return str.Substring(0, Math.Min(length, str.Length));
    } 
}
```

And then using/calling it by doing:

```
var s = "foobar".Left(3)
// variable s will now contain "foo"
```

Comment: any equivalent to : Strings.Left?

Comment: String.Substring(int index, int count) http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.string.substring(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the following SO Question, it may provide you with a clear cut solution for a c# implementation: [.Net equivalent of the old vb left(string, length) function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/844059/net-equivalent-of-the-old-vb-leftstring-length-function)

It involves creating an extension method. The code looks a bit like this (ref: this is the same code as in the SO question I mentioned, all credit to them.)

```
public static class Utils {
    public static string Left(this string str, int length)
    {
        return str.Substring(0, Math.Min(length, str.Length));
    } 
}
```

And then calling it by doing

```
var s = "foobar".Left(3)
// variable s will now contain "foo"
```

Answer (score 0):

I know, that you didn't ask for, but it might be worth taking a look at the `System.Text.Regularexpressions.Regex`-Class (available for c# and vb). This class provides many powerful operations an strings using compact patterns, which have its own syntax. The performance might be worse in some cases, but the readability increases.