# Additional information: Index and length must refer to a location within the string

Tags: c#

I have a substring which is defined as:

```
<p>@Html.Raw(item.Post.Substring(0, 300))...</p>
```

The text I'm entering far exceeds 300 characters, but I'm still getting the error above. I thought the second param on the substring method was supposed to be the number of characters you want to cut to?

Unless I'm wrong and I'm missing something?

Comment: Try following `item.Post.Substring(0, Math.Min(300, item.Post.Length));`

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9556008/html-raw-is-not-working-asp-net-mvc) will help.

Comment: Perfect thanks :) - If you wanna pop that in as an answer I'll mark it as right :)

Comment: @WebDevelopWolf Ok, i will write as an answer.  Thanks ))

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.Net equivalent of the old vb left(string, length) function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/844059/net-equivalent-of-the-old-vb-leftstring-length-function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following

```
item.Post.Substring(0, Math.Min(300, item.Post.Length));
```